# Every Tannakian category over an algebraically closed field is neutral

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, tannakian-category

In *Tannakian Categories* by P. Deligne and J. S. Milne (footnote 16 of the november 2018 version), it is said that

> Every Tannakian category over an algebraically closed field is neutral (letter of Deligne, November 30, 2011).

I wonder why is it so. Is there some reference for this?

(The Corollaire 6.20 in Deligne's *Catégories Tannakiennes* implies this whenever our category has a $\otimes$-generator. I don't quite see how to go from this to what is stated above.)

Comment: Theorem 6.4.1 in Coulembier's paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.02452

Comment: That's perfect @D.-C.Cisinski. If you would like, please write this as an answer and I'll gladly accept it :)

Comment: Deligne's letter is on the web, for example, here
https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/Deligne_on_fiber_functors.pdf

Comment: Just in case this may be helpful to someone, yesterday Milne (I think) updated this paper to contain Deligne's letter.